# typescript dependency injection in super()

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance, dependency-injection, superclass

I have a class called restService like bellow:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestService {

  private baseUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.baseUrl = environment.jsonServerUrl;
  }
}
```

and I have another class extends RestService class called UploaderService like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploaderService extends RestService {

  constructor() {
    super(); // error occurred here!
  }
}
```

but when I write super method error occurred because RestService Class has Dependency Injection in its constructor, and I don't know how can I inject that in the super.
How can I fix that?

Comment: If the constructor in `UploaderService` does nothing, you could drop it altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameters of the super class need to be repeated and passed to the super call:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploaderService extends RestService {
  constructor (http: HttpClient){
    super(http);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, It's not a copy. we answered at same time;)

Comment: @MostafaSaadatnia - JonasMS's answer was posted before this one. Please check your facts.

Comment: @MostafaSaadatnia - For your information, you can see the exact time in a tooltip when the mouse is over "answered ... mins ago". JonasMH answered exactly 12 seconds earlier.

Answer (score 8):

You can repeat the parameters, as shown in other answers.

There is another way, though, which is handy when you have many parameters and extended classes : use `Injector` to get the dependencies in the base class.

Then, you only need to repeat the "Injector" injection in derived classes, which can save a  lot of space and mind sanity when you have many services to inject in base class, but not a lot in derived class.

```
import { MyService } from './my.service';
import { FooService } from './foo.service';
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

export class Base {
    protected myService: MyService;
    protected fooService: FooService;

  constructor (protected injector: Injector) {
    this.myService = injector.get(MyService);
    this.fooService = injector.get(FooService);
  }
}

export class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(protected injector: Injector) {
    super(injector);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass through the injection

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UploaderService extends RestService {

  constructor(http: HttpClient) {
    super(http);
  }
}
```